# Using VBA I Need to Break a String into 80 Character Chunks

Tags: excel, vba

Using Excel VBA I am writing records to a DB2 data file.
A field that holds the description is 80 characters.
Data format is recseq, etqindx, seqno, description.

My Description string may be several hundred characters.
I want to loop thru the string and write a record for each 80 characters.
This is as far as I have got.

```
On Error Resume Next
        logindex2 = (Now() - #1/1/1970#) * 86400000
    
        recInsert = "Insert Into webprddt1.wqmsnxtid" & _
        "(recseq, crtdt) Values(" & logindex2 & ",current_timestamp)"
        
        oConn.Execute (recInsert)   
seqno = 1
        
Do
        
oConn.Execute "Insert Into webprddt1.wqmsetqd1(recseq,etqindx,seqno,descriptn)" _
& "Values(" & logindex2 & "," & logindex & "," & seqno & ",'" & ncDescription & "')"
        
Loop Until IsEmpty(ncDescription)
```

Comment: What is the problem? If this code does not produce the desired result, maybe comment out `On Error Resume Next` as that will hide any problems the code comes across

Comment: The problem is I do not know how to code getting the 80 character chunks from the original string.

Comment: I would envision within the loop getting the first 80 characters, write the record to database, reduce the original string by the 80 characters, get next 80 characters, etc

Comment: I would have a `Do while Len(myString) >80` loop and write the first 80 characters where you need them. You can start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/keywords/string-manipulation-summary) for manipuplating string in VBA

Answer (score 0):

This should break it down: (You did not provide the whole Sub/Function, other details may cause an issue)

```
On Error Resume Next
        logindex2 = (Now() - #1/1/1970#) * 86400000
    
        recInsert = "Insert Into webprddt1.wqmsnxtid" & _
        "(recseq, crtdt) Values(" & logindex2 & ",current_timestamp)"
        
        oConn.Execute (recInsert)
seqno = 1

Dim rString As String, cString As String
rString = ncDescription
Do While Len(rString) >= 80
    'Get 80 Left Characters
    cString = Left(rString, 80)
    'Remove the 80 Characters for the next loop
    rString = Right(rString, (Len(rString) - 80))
    oConn.Execute "Insert Into webprddt1.wqmsetqd1(recseq,etqindx,seqno,descriptn)" _
    & "Values(" & logindex2 & "," & logindex & "," & seqno & ",'" & cString & "')"
    seqno = seqno + 1
Loop
'If there is anything remaining in the string do a final insert
If Len(rString > 0) Then
    cString = rString
    oConn.Execute "Insert Into webprddt1.wqmsetqd1(recseq,etqindx,seqno,descriptn)" _
    & "Values(" & logindex2 & "," & logindex & "," & seqno & ",'" & cString & "')"
End If
```